# SMS via SMPP: How to determine number of parts in multipart sms

Tags: smpp, telecommunication

Im' sending sms messages via EasySmpp library (http://sourceforge.net/projects/easysmpp/). In case of messages over 160 characters long it internally uses data_sm command.

The question is how can I determine number of parts of sms message that arrives to the phone. My operator charges me per part so obviously I need that information.

Of course I can count it myself (message length / 160 or message length / 70 in case of UTF-8), but is there a better solution? Maybe smpp has a field for this?

m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar discussion with our [SMS gateway provider](http://www.innovativetxt.com/services/sms_api_gateway.htm) yesterday. This is explained in detail here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Message_size

Comment: Thanx! So assuming I'm sending 16bit unicode strings the algoritm should be following:
if (message.Length <=70)
 return 1;
else
 return Math.Ceiling(message.Length/67);